# Duplicated text values using ggplot geomhline

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Sorry, im learning R now, and im finding trouble to identify why am i having duplicated values in my graph.
Basically i just want to show the mean value from table data.summary, but it is repeating according to the other means i am plotting from a different table.

```
    ggplot(summary(rating_cat_emm), 
           aes(x=reorder(Category, -emmean), 
               y=emmean, 
               ymin=lower.CL, 
               ymax=upper.CL)) + 
       geom_point(col="magenta", size=1) + 
       geom_hline(data=data.summary, 
                  mapping=aes(yintercept=mean), 
                  color="darkblue") +
       geom_text(aes(label=round(data.summary$mean,2)),
                 vjust=15, 
                 size=3) +
       geom_linerange(col="darkorchid4") + 
       geom_text(aes(label=round(emmean,2)),
                 hjust=0.5, 
                 vjust=-2, 
                 size=3) + 
       labs(x="Category", 
            y="rating", 
            subtitle="Error bars are 95% CIs"))
```

[image]

Comment: We would be able to provide more help if we had a reproducible example.  That said, I suspect the first `geom_text()` call is the one plotting the 3.76 values.  Removing that should remove those values from the plot, if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to guess without a reproducible example. However, I'd bet that this is because you are passing the same value as label in the geom_text. I would think that data.summary$mean is constant. So geom_text is reusing the label for all values in data. You should pass data.summary in the data argument of geom_text.

All that said, it would be easier if you provided a reproducible example of the datasets.